# website updates doubts!! help needed

Tags: html, web, content-management-system

I'm developing a news website..i'v completed the layout and front end works.. the news website i created with a particular layout in which the latest news are sorted in right corner and headline news displayed in left corneer.. and my doubt starts here.. Do i have to modify the html sheet everytime when a latest news comes?? ... Do i have to change the latest news in right corner too?? I'v no idea what is web CMS..  And also how can i post new ariticle in my website? Do i have to create a html file whenever i post a new article? help me plz :(

Comment: The server backend providing the data should be able to specify which news is latest and which news is headline, and you can just stick the content in the corresponding spot.

Comment: Your question is very broad. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what kind of questions this site is for. You might be better off doing a web search for "content management systems". After learning about what they do and choosing one or a few that you might like to work with, this would be a great place to ask specific questions about how to implement the CMS when you run into a problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to learn dynamic programming languages etc like PHP, MySQL to make your site dynamic and then wish to implement it then its fine. Go with the above said comment.

Else I would say, if your aim to post new contents, headlines, news etc dynamically without any issues and bugs in your website. Then go with well developed and famous CMS.

This link may help you to get the basics intro of CMS
[Basic intro on CMS](http://www.aliencoders.com/content/cms-complete-package-web-designing)

Try using wordpress or Joomla or Drupal. If you are ok with basic things then I may guide for the next level :)

Comment: yea thank yu so much :) i'l go with CMS.. I have built the front end of the website and is it ok to use the same in the mentioned CMS? :)

Comment: Drupal is not a good place to start, I expect that the same is true for Joomla. Wordpress would likely be the best option, you don't need to know any PHP, but can experiment if you want to.

Comment: All have its own purpose codewaggle. You may see that link which i provided. www.aliencoders.com is based on drupal and tourismandfood.com is based on wordpress     All it depends whats your purpose. If it's just for blogging, wordpress is best. Company website but with dynamic things- Joomla seems fine. Big working website with blog forums etc - Drupal comes handy...want only forum phpbb and smf is ok. So all it depends upon your needs my friend

Comment: @user1481873 If it served your purpose you may opt for the best answer among all the response given. Otherwise it will always show as unsolved questions.

Answer (score 2):

You could definitely update the HTML file every time if that is how you want to go about doing it...

But, you have a long way to go if you are looking to build your own custom dynamic website.  You should probably start by researching a lot into PHP and MySql.  There are a bunch of good resources online about these and it is server side scripting languages which help to create a dynamic website such as you describe.

You could also possible start a blog blogger which can handle most everything for you, leaving it up to you to generate the content.

Good luck!

Comment: yea i'v managed blog for some time .. updating an html file evrytime will be tedious... I knew the basics of php and mysql..i'l look into the php and mysql deeper.. thank yu mate :)

Comment: No problem.  As Jassi mentioned below, no need to reinvent the wheel - checkout pre-made CMS scripts which are already robust and give you a lot of punch right out of the bag.  You could also look into learning Smarty which is a templating language that a few CMS use to display user facing content so that you can keep the look and feel of layout you have created.  But again find the CMS you are most comfortable with first, then go and edit it to meet your needs.